# How to convert the DN values of Resourcesat-2 LISS-3 images to Radiance?

Tags: toa-calibration, liss-iii

Does somebody knows How to convert to Radiance the Resourcesat-2 LISS-3 images?

I found a paper "Pre-flight Radiometric and Spectral Calibration of Resourcesat-2ALISS3* payload", where they determined some parameters. But I´m not sure. I´ve also tryed the SACRS2, of Vishal Pathak called at the paper "Retrieval of Surface reflectance from Resourcesat-2 AWiFS, LISS-3 and LISS-4 data using SACRS2 scheme", but I was not able to put the right input data (RPC, META, geom?)

Answer (score 1):

I could not use SACRS2 for LISS3 images. The results are not good. I also made some tests and I found that the approach using the formula Lrad = (DN / MaxGray) * (Lmax - Lmin) + Lmin, as some people recommend only works if you use the MaxGray value of the scene. Not 255. The best results I found it was using the formula: Lrad= DN*gain+offset. And the coefficients I have used can be found on the paper "Pre-flight Radiometric and Spectral Calibration of Resourcesat-2ALISS3*payload" (Seth et al., 2016), but you have to pay attention to the units of the spectral measures (mW/cm².sr.micro).